# _TABLE_SUFFIX on subselect

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to using _TABLE_SUFFIX as parameter into subselect

```
SELECT 
  A._TABLE_SUFFIX,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      `analytics_202222094.events_*` AS B
    WHERE
      B._TABLE_SUFFIX = A._TABLE_SUFFIX
      AND B.event_name = 'session_start' 
  )
FROM `analytics_202222094.events_*` AS A 
GROUP BY A._TABLE_SUFFIX
```

Comment: what is the question? please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX  AS table_suffix,
  COUNTIF(event_name = 'session_start')
FROM `analytics_202222094.events_*` 
GROUP BY _TABLE_SUFFIX
```

As you can see you don't need subquery here at all - but in cases when you will need  - use alias for reserved field names started with underscore - like _TABLE_SUFFIX, _PARTITION, _TABLE_ , _FILE_, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Give it an alias:

```
SELECT MAX(id), ts
FROM (
  SELECT *, _table_suffix ts
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201703_*` 
) a
GROUP BY 2
```

Otherwise you'll get the error

> Invalid field name "_table_suffix". Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, *TABLE*, *FILE* and _ROW_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Ok done, but the result is not corret:
SELECT 
  ts,
  (select Count(*) from `analytics_202222094.events_*` as b where b._TABLE_SUFFIX = ts)

FROM (
  SELECT *, _table_suffix as ts
  FROM  `analytics_202222094.events_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20191126'
) a
GROUP BY 
  ts